# Need clarification on mutually exclusive sets!

Tags: probability

Firstly does mutually exclusive apply for **two** events only? So if we have A1,...,An events where n>2 and their intersection is zero/the empty set are they mutually exclusive, if not **what are they called?** So basically can a set A1,...,An be called mutually exclusive or not.

Like for independence of a set A1,...,An we have to show all possible combinations are independent, is there a similar notion for a set to be mutually exclusive or does that not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have $n$-mutually exclusive events. Also they are called collectively exhaustive if the probability of at least one event happening is equal to $1$.

Contrary to my previous edits, you only need to show **any** two events do not intersect, as If an event does not intersect any other then it cannot intersect more than one event. Therefore $n$ events are mutually exclusive if no two events intersect.